# form made with echo dosen't call php function

Tags: php, forms

I have tried to make a ToDo list for a user. In the code below, wish adding button works fine and calls 'add_wish()' function but 'delete'/'update' button doesn't call relevant function. Rather call a file ''. Tried searching forums for hours. Why this is happening and how can I call relevent functions using this approch of extracting data from database. My code:

```
<body>
<?php
    global $id, $adatabase;
    include 'connect_to_database.php';
    $adatabase = new database('localhost','root','');

function delete_wish($post_id) {
    echo 'BLAH BLAH BLAH';
    if(!empty($new_todo)) {
        global $id,$adatabase;

        $query = "DELTE FROM todolist WHERE post_id = '".$post_id."''";
        if ($query_run = mysqli_query($adatabase->mysqli_link,$query)) {
            get_user_todos($id);
        } else 'Failed to add new wish.Please try again later!';
    }
}

function update_wish($post_id) {
    echo 'OKA';
}

    function get_user_todos($user_id) {
        global $id, $adatabase;
        $id= $user_id;
        echo $user_id;

        $query = "SELECT todo,post_id FROM todolist WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'";
        if ($query_run = mysqli_query($adatabase->mysqli_link,$query)) {
            ?>
            <div id="todo_list">
                <table border="10" cellpadding="10">
                    <?php

                    while($query_data = $query_run->fetch_row()) {
                        echo '<tr>';

                        echo '<td>'.$query_data[0].'</td>';
                        echo "<td> <form method='post' action=\"<?php update_wish(".$query_data[1].");?>\">  <input type='submit' value='update'>  </form> </td>";
                        echo "<td> <form method='post' action=\"<?php delete_wish(".$query_data[1].");?>\"> <input type='submit' value='delete'> </form> </td>";

                        echo '</tr>';
                 }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>

        <?php

        }
}

    function add_wish() {
        global $id;
        if(isset($_POST['new_todo'])) {
            $new_todo = $_POST['new_todo'];
            if(!empty($new_todo)) {
                global $id,$adatabase;

                $query = "INSERT INTO todolist (todo,user_id) VALUE ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($adatabase->mysqli_link,$new_todo)."','".$id."')";
                if ($query_run = mysqli_query($adatabase->mysqli_link,$query)) {
                    get_user_todos($id);
                } else 'Failed to add new wish.Please try again later!';
            }
        }
    }

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        get_user_todos($_SESSION['user_id']);

        ?>
            <form method="post" action=" <?php add_wish(); ?>">
                <textarea rows="4" cols="8" name="new_todo"></textarea>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        <?php
    }else
        header('Location: login.php');
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you get your `echo` in both functions?

Comment: nope.rather this links came up in browser :

after clicking delete button-> http://localhost/projects/simple-todolist/<? php echo delete_wish(7);?>

after clicking update button->
http://localhost/projects/simple-todolist/<?php echo update_wish(7);?>

N.B: 7 is the relative post_id

Comment: That's kinda strange. I would suggest to rewrite your code and add new hidden field with value of what you pass in function (which is `$query_data[1]`). In action you can write just empty string `""` and then check for `$_POST` in `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {`.